# Header height in dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have got the dataTable working.
The only thing is that its header is of double the normal height.
This seems to be due to very wide llist box ;

"Show [A wide list box showing options 10,25,50,All] ..line break..
     Entries"

Actually this should fit in one line; but due to the width of list box, it takes 2nd line on header, making the header too fat.
Similarly, the footer (pager) is also having double height.
How do I fix this?

Thanks,
Vineet
The code is from web2py framework (based on python)
In the header--

```
script tag    
$(document).ready(function() { 
   var oTable = $('#dept_table').dataTable( { 
    "bJQueryUI": true, 
    "sScrollY": "200px",  
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]], 
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
  }); 
});
end script tag
```

In the body--

```
<h1>Department Master</h1>
<input type='submit' id='addNew' value='Add New Department' /><br /><br />
<table id="dept_table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Department ID</th>
<th>Department Name</th>
<th>Link</th> 
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{for department in departments:}}
<tr>
<td>{{=department['deptid']}}</td>
<td>{{=department['deptnm']}}</td>
<td>
{{=A('edit',_href=URL('frmDeptSave',vars={'did':department['deptid'],'dnm':department['deptnm']}),_class='edturl')}}
{{=A('delete',_href=URL('frmDeptDel',vars={'did':department['deptid'],'dnm':department['deptnm']}),_class='delurl')}}
</td>
</tr>
{{pass}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Pl. tell me if you require anything else for suggesting a solution.
---Vineet

Answer (score 4):

```
    <style>.dataTables_length select{ width: 50px}</style>
```

Finally, this worked for me.
@Nicola, thanks for the inputs which were very useful to me.

Comment: This should probably be a comment on Nicola's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the double hight is due to the fact that you are using jQuery ui, so try setting

```
"bJQueryUI": false,
```

if this doesn't solve your problem, try posting your full code (html and css, maybe on jsfiddle)  so we can help you better

Comment: removing "bJQueryUI": true doesn't solve the issue. I tried that. I have edited my OP to include the code. Pl. help.

Comment: I have included "jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom", and also a "base.css" file for web2py framework. Do you suspect the base.css file? Pl. tell me what property should I check in it. Can I attach it here?

Comment: Umph! I increased the page width & now the header is in 1 row. But this is not a permanent solution. Pl. tell me how can I redule the width of list box showing no. of rows to display. If that is reduced, the header will fit in 1 row. On the dataTables site, it is like that.

Comment: If you need to style it you could use: `.dataTables_length select{ Your css here}`

Comment: That's correct. But any idea why it is getting lenghened? With only basic initialisation, I think it should be of minimum length (as we can see on dataTables.net demo page)

Comment: Yes it should be, and i used a set-up like yours without problems in a project i did. My only idea is that there is a css conflict somewhere, but usually it's a nightmare to spot: it's simpler to overryde the css again! :)

Comment: I did that (overridden the .dataTables_length select properties. It adjusted the select box size. But the 2 line header remains as it is. Any other property is there for header height?